# multikey dictionary in java

Tags: java, data-structures

Do we have a multikey dictionary data structure available in Java?

If I need to maintain a big population of data which can be queried by multiple criteria - eg citizens to be queried by either uniqueID(social security etc) or phone number - is there a variation of dictionary/map which can support this?

The point to note in this used-case is queries being much more frequent than inserts/updates.

Comment: cannot you use a dbms?